# How to execute an Xcode app on iOS 16 beta device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios16

Since I updated my **iPhone** on `iOS 16 beta`, I can't execute my apps in development on my device.

When I connect my phone, and try to execute the app on it, I get the following error:

> The run destination MyiPhone is not valid for Running the scheme
> 'App'. Xcode doesn’t support iPhone’s iOS 16.0 (20A5312j).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You would need to update your computer and Xcode too.

Comment: You will need Xcode 14 beta.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either update your `Xcode` to use the beta version(7.3Gb), or add `iOS 16` to `Xcode`'s DeviceSupport folder(8.02Mb): [iOS-DeviceSupport](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport)